# PPT 2013 add macro to image?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, macros

I have a back button which is an image with an action linked to it.  That works fine, but there is a background video which, when I go back to a slide won't play by default, which doesn't look good.  I found a solution involving a macro [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-powerpoint/ppt-2010-video-does-not-play-when-viewing-previous/df04d6ac-2bf3-42a2-9cd1-cff69a5bdf31), but the only problem is I don't know how to add a macro to an image, or even if it's possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Assign an action to an image](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/assign-an-action-to-a-built-in-button-or-picture-HA010338338.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010338365) states -

> 1. On the View tab, in the Presentation Views group, click Normal.
> 2. Click the picture, clip art, or button shape that you want to change.
> 3. On the Insert tab, in the Links group, click Action.
> 4. To change the behavior of the picture, clip art, or button shape, in the Action Settings dialog box, click either the Mouse Click tab or
>      the Mouse Over tab.
> 5. To choose the action that takes place when you click or move the pointer over the picture, clip art, or button shape, do one of the
>      following:
>      *To run a macro, click Run macro, and then select the macro that you want to run. The Run macro settings are available only if your
>      presentation contains a macro. When you save the presentation, you
>      must save it as a PowerPoint Macro-enabled Show. For more information
>      about macros see [run a
>      macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/powerpoint-help/run-a-macro-HA010338325.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010338365)*